# Removing whitespaces in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex code to remove spaces, first word, brackets and all numbers.

I have the following text:

```
{a, 1, b, 4, c, 6, d, 8}
```

I am interested in: b, c and d while excluding a.

This regex: `"\,([^{^,+^\d-}]*)"` gives me b, c and d but with spaces.

I've tried this: `"\,([^{^,+^\d-^\s+}]*)"` but with no luck.

Any suggesting?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in? Because trimming the `{}` and splitting at `,` would be a lot easier.

Comment: The language tool is C#

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a regex? I can think of other ways to do this that would probably be just as fast, performance-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the easiest solution would be to extract all letters and ignore the first match:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, @"\p{L}+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(match => match.Value)
                   .ToList();
```

That is, if you don't need to validate the input string format. If you do, you could use the following pattern beforehand:

```
^\{(?:(?:\s*\w+\s*,\s)*\s*\w+)?\s*\}$
```

Which means:

```
^\{                     # Opening brace
  (?:                   # Optionally:
    (?:\s*\w+\s*,\s)*   #   Words followed by commas 0 to n times
    \s*\w+              #   Followed by a word
  )?                    
\s*                     # Optional whitespace
\}$                     # Closing brace
```

[Demo of the validation regex](http://regex101.com/r/xP8vO0/1)